# how to use multiple latitude and longitude in Marker(React native MapView)

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-maps-markers, react-native-maps

I have more than 10 latitude and longitude, I want to display them in Marker. How can i show them in marker for react native mapView. Already I have tried to do a function an call the function in return which is not giving anything in map.
anyone can help me if I have done anything wrong or how to fix this and i can show my latitude and longitude in Marker.

To call latitude and longitude I used for loop to get all the latitude and longitude.

Please help me to display all the location (latitude & longitude) in Marker.
ThankYou for your Trying in advance!

```
   function markers() {
        for (let i = 0; i < vp?.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < vp[i]?.length; j++) {
                let longitude = vp[i][0];
                let latitude = vp[i][1];
                <Marker
                    coordinate={{
                        longitude: longitude,
                        latitude: latitude,
                    }}
                ></Marker>
            }
        }
    }
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <MapView
                style={styles.map}
                initialRegion={{
                    longitude: 113.3661,
                    latitude: 4.7631,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
                }}>
                {markers}              
            </MapView>
        </View>
    );
```

Comment: Have you been able to show one  marker?

Comment: after trying use this {markers} i haven't be able to show one marker yet.

Comment: Could you please share the data structure of your latitude and longitude because it is important for looping. your markers function does not return anything but it should return lists of elements.

Comment: [[114.6191, 5.789], [114.67213, 5.76543], [115.1234, 7654], [116.678, 5.123456], [115.35783, 6.4567]]

Comment: i am having this format data by fetch from API.

Comment: const markers = vp?.map(location=>(
      <Marker
            coordinate={{
              longitude: location[0],
              latitude: location[1],
              }}
      />
    ))
Replace your markers function by this line of code.

Comment: i tried your last tips, still i'm not getting any marker in map.

Comment: getting an error: Render Error : null is not an object (evaluating 'location[0]')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this with a map like this simpler and with less code. You forgot to return the marker component.

```
  return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <MapView
                style={styles.map}
                initialRegion={{
                    longitude: 113.3661,
                    latitude: 4.7631,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
                }}>
                // change your code here
                {vp.map((m)=><Marker
                    coordinate={{
                        longitude: m[0],
                        latitude: m[1],
                    }}
                ></Marker>)}              
            </MapView>
        </View>
    );
```

[image]

Comment: you already see that i have nested array in my data structure, so i have to change based on that?

Comment: It will work. No need to change.

Comment: but for me it's not working Boss. i can't see any marker in Map.

Comment: Render error: null is not an object (evaluating 'm[0]')

Comment: @user19891844 it's working please change the map's initial coordinates. I've updated the answer with a screenshot.

Comment: thanks! it's Working for me finally, your effort helps me lot to get confident and keep trying.